# local storage index.js cordova

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, cordova

I am following the cordova tutorial on tutorialpoints.com.

At Step 2 Adding Event Listeners to set and show local storage there is a sentence which is not easily comprehended by me precisely at: "Cordova security policy doesn't allow inline events so we will add event listeners inside index.js files."

What is that supposed to mean? Where should I put these inside the index.js?

```
document.getElementById("setLocalStorage").addEventListener("click", setLocalStorage);
document.getElementById("showLocalStorage").addEventListener("click", showLocalStorage);
document.getElementById("removeProjectFromLocalStorage").addEventListener("click", removeProjectFromLocalStorage);
document.getElementById("getLocalStorageByKey").addEventListener("click", getLocalStorageByKey);

var localStorage = window.localStorage;`
```

Inside variable app but outside the functions, or inside any of the functions?

It is driving me crazy!!!!

Comment: I think inline is meant like `<button onclick="setLocalStorage();">whatever</button>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put it in document redy like

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
document.getElementById("setLocalStorage").addEventListener("click", setLocalStorage);
document.getElementById("showLocalStorage").addEventListener("click", showLocalStorage);
document.getElementById("removeProjectFromLocalStorage").addEventListener("click", removeProjectFromLocalStorage);
document.getElementById("getLocalStorageByKey").addEventListener("click", getLocalStorageByKey); 
}
```

Comment: var app = { initialize: function() {document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);},
 onDeviceReady: function() {this.receivedEvent('deviceready');},
 receivedEvent: function(id) {var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
  var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
   var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
     listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);}};
app.initialize();

Comment: You can put it anywhere. But in var should be benifitial for build perpose.

Comment: Go with this link repository  it might help you: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start

Comment: Thanks a million. And where should I put the var localStorage, also inside the document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {}?

Comment: Yes You can add it in same event if you want to initialize in on page load. Your welcome if you found this answer helpful please accept it and upvote it.

Comment: And where should I put the function for setting the local storage? also inside the var app but outside all of other functions?

Comment: If you dont have very big app then put everting in var app folder. and making it global is more benifitial for reusebility. please upvote answer and useful comments.

Comment: I've added some functions to set and show local storage. But on my phone shows only that the app is 'connecting to device' and not 'device is ready'. How can I fix it so that the app works? http://pastebin.com/LqMrgdT2

Comment: For that i have to check code buddy. Dou you have any repository?

Comment: I've added my code on my previous comment on pastebin. I don't have any repository. I am a bleeding newbie :/

Comment: onDeviceReady: function() {
        this.receivedEvent('deviceready'); var localStorage = window.localStorage;
    },

Comment: Yah thats why i put it in.. And first check if you get **window.localStorage** or not.

Comment: My updated code http://pastebin.com/eP9n3Nyg. Do you have an example of a working index.js with the use of local storage?

Comment: [This Link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start/blob/master/www/js/index.js) might help you

Comment: So, I have put var localStorage in onDeviceReady function but my android phone shows only "connecting to device", and buttons "set local storage", "show local storage" and to other buttons are not working :/  http://pastebin.com/XTDhGKM5

Comment: I think there is some issue with window.localStorage debug whole code step by step. From initialize to the end. you will get clue.